# Is it semantically correct to have multiple h2 tags in one HTML document?

Tags: html

Is it semantically correct to have multiple h2 or any header tags in one HTML document?

Comment: Do you mean _heading_ or _header_ tags? That makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes semantically that is correct.

**Edit**
It does not look like the w3 has any restriction on the max occurrences of header entities.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html#edef-H1

http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/sgml/dtd.html#heading

Comment: Thanks, just for my records do you have a src

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Note that you can also group headers in [header groups](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element).